# Weird output in beginner Phonebook app in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm new to C and I'm working on trying to create the typical beginners phonebook app. I've seen a lot of different links on google that show examples of the phonebook app, but nothing that shows what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically what I'm wanting to do is create a structure that has first name, last name, and 2 phone numbers, then I want to create 2 different functions for each of those. For each variable in the structure I would have one that sets the input, and then another one that reads the input. This gives me 8 functions, but then I want to add three more functions, one for adding 11each new contract to the structure, one for deleting a contact and then one for viewing the phonebook. Right now I'm focusing on the adding function and viewing function. My issue is that I am getting very weird output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef struct friends_contact{
       char First_Name[10];
       char Last_Name[10];
       char home[15];
       char cell[15];

}fr;

void menu(fr*friends ,int* counter,int user_entry, char* nullStr,int i);
void setFirst(fr*,int *,int i);
char getFirst(fr*,int*,char*,int i);
void setLast(fr*friends, int* counter, int i);
char getLast(fr*friends ,int* counter,char *nullStr, int i);
void add_contact(fr*friends,int* counter,int i);
void show_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter,char *nullStr, int i);


int main()
{
  int user_entry=0;
  fr friends[5];
  int counter=0;
  char nullStr[21] = {"\0"}; 
  int i=0;

 menu(friends, &counter,user_entry,nullStr,i);
 getch();
 return 0;
}

void menu(fr*friends,int* counter,int user_entry,char *nullStr,int i)
{
  do{
  printf("Phone Book Application\n");
  printf("1) Add friend\n2) Delete friend\n3) Show a friend\n4) Show phonebook\n5)Exit);   
 scanf("%d", &user_entry);
  if(user_entry==1){

                    add_contact(friends,counter,i);
                    }
   if(user_entry==4){
                  show_contact(friends, counter,nullStr,i);
                   } 
   }while(user_entry!=5);                 
 }

 void setFirst(fr*friends, int* counter, int i)
{
 (*counter)++;
 printf("Enter a first name \n");
 scanf("%s",&friends[*counter-1].First_Name);
}
void setLast(fr*friends, int* counter, int i)
{
 (*counter)++;
 printf("Enter a first name \n");
 scanf("%s",&friends[*counter-1].Last_Name);
}
char getFirst(fr*friends ,int* counter,char *nullStr, int i)
{
     for(i=0; i<*counter; i++)
     {
        if (strcmp(nullStr, friends[i].First_Name) != 0) 
        {
           printf("%s\n", friends[i].First_Name);
        }
     }

return *friends[i].First_Name;
}

char getLast(fr*friends ,int* counter,char *nullStr, int i)
{
     for(i=0; i<*counter; i++)
     {
        if (strcmp(nullStr, friends[i].Last_Name) != 0) 
        {
           printf("%s\n", friends[i].Last_Name);
        }
     }

 return *friends[i].Last_Name;
}
void add_contact(fr*friends,int* counter,int i)
{ 
 setFirst(friends,counter,i); 
 setLast(friends,counter,i);
}    

void show_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter,char *nullStr, int i)
{
 getFirst(friends,counter,nullStr,i);
 getLast(friends,counter,nullStr,i);
}
```

Here is the output that I get now:

```
Enter a first name
john
Enter a first name
smith
Phone Book Application
1) Add friend
2) Delete friend
3) Show a friend
4) Show phone book
5) Exit

4
john
╝ ♠

smith
```

my results are equally as weird when i add another name to the list. Whats weird is I only started having these problems after I created the last name function. When I entered just first names it worked fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Usually that happens when you don't null terminate your string. Considering we only can only see the function declarations, we won't be much help.

Comment: You can only see the function declarations? I posted the whole code. hmm..

Comment: you were right I forgot to null terminate my string, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I made some changes and I paste you the whole code (including the main)
I got rid of the variable nullStr. When you want to see if a name is balnk you can use strlen(string) which gives you the size of that string. If the size is 0 it means the string is blank.

Here is the code:

> `#` include< stdio.h >
>     # include < string.h >
>
> typedef struct friends_contact{
>
> > ```
> >   char First_Name[10];
> >    char Last_Name[10];
> >    char home[15];
> >    char cell[15];
> > ```
>
> }fr;

```
void menu(fr*friends ,int* counter,int user_entry,int i);
void setFirst(fr*,int *,int i);
char getFirst(fr*,int i);
void setLast(fr*friends, int* counter, int i);
char getLast(fr*friends , int i);
void add_contact(fr*friends,int* counter,int i);
void show_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i);
```

> int main()
>    {
>
> > ```
> > int user_entry=0;
> > fr friends[5];
> > int counter=0;
> > int i=0;
> > menu(friends, &counter,user_entry,i);
> > return 0;
> > ```
> >
> > }
>
> void menu(fr*friends,int* counter,int user_entry, int i)
>   {
>
> > do{
> >
> > > ```
> > > printf("Phone Book Application\n");
> > > printf("1) Add friend\n2) Delete friend\n3) Show a friend\n
> > >                4) Show phonebook\n5)Exit");
> > > ```
> > >
> > > > scanf("%d", &user_entry);
> > > >
> > > > > ```
> > > > > if(user_entry==1){
> > > > >             add_contact(friends,counter,i);
> > > > >             }
> > > > >    if(user_entry==4){
> > > > >           show_contact(friends, counter,i);
> > > > >            } 
> > > > >    }while(user_entry!=5);
> > > > > ```
> > > > >
> > > > > }
>
> void setFirst(fr*friends, int* counter, int i)
>   {
>
> > ```
> >     printf("Enter a first name \n");
> >     scanf("%s",friends[*counter].First_Name);
> > ```
> >
> > }
>
> void setLast(fr*friends, int* counter, int i)
>   {
>
> > ```
> >     printf("Enter a first name \n");
> >     scanf("%s",friends[*counter].Last_Name);
> > ```
> >
> > }
>
> void add_contact(fr*friends,int* counter,int i)
>   {
>
> > ```
> >     setFirst(friends,counter,i); 
> >     setLast(friends,counter,i);
> >     (*counter)++;
> > ```
> >
> > }
>
> void show_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i) {
>
> > ```
> > for( i = 0; i < *counter; i++)
> > ```
> >
> > > ```
> > >   if (strlen(friends[i].First_Name) && strlen(friends[i].Last_Name) )
> > >     {
> > > ```
> > >
> > > > ```
> > > >             getFirst(friends, i);
> > > >             getLast(friends, i);
> > > >     }
> > > > ```
> > > >
> > > > }
>
> char getFirst(fr*friends , int pos) {
>
> > ```
> >    printf("%s ", friends[pos].First_Name);
> >    return *friends[pos].First_Name;
> > ```
> >
> > }
>
> char getLast(fr*friends , int pos) {
>
> > ```
> >       printf("%s\n", friends[pos].Last_Name);
> >       return *friends[pos].Last_Name;
> > ```
> >
> > }

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are:

1) in function setFirst `scanf("%s",&friends[*counter-1].First_Name);`
  2) in function setLast  `scanf("%s",&friends[*counter-1].Last_Name);`

In both cases, when you use scanf for a string variable, you should not put the '&' in front of the variable, because a string variable is already a address to the first element of the string.

This shold work:

1) in function setFirst `scanf("%s",friends[*counter-1].First_Name);`
  2) in function setLast  `scanf("%s",friends[*counter-1].Last_Name);`

Comment: Taking the address of an array is exactly the same as taking the address of it's first element, FYI.

Comment: I fixed the weird character issues by setting `fr friends[5];` to NULL. But now my issue is that it when I enter two names my output comes out like this
 
`johnjanesmith
doe` instead of `john smith` `jane doe`. is this just an issue with the way I am printing the names?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that both `setFirst` and `setLast` are incrementing the counter.  So the first name is filled for the first entry and the last name for the second entry.

Comment: So the counter should only be in of those 2 functions? lets say I take it out of the `setFirst` wont that just continue to overwrite anything i put in? ex. first contact is jim, next contact is mike, and when you go to `show Phonebook` there is only mike because jim has been overwritten.

Comment: The counter should only be incremented once per user.  Where you increment it is up to you.  The problem now is that after the call to setFirst and setLast, the counter will have value 2 (instead of 1). In my opinion, the calling function should increment the counter.  The utility (e.g., setFirst) should not increment the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Your bad output is because when you call the function `showContacts`, it first calls the function `getFirst` and then the function `getLast` and when you add the names `john smith` and `jane doe` the function `getFirst` will print `john jane` and function `getLast` prints `smith doe`
For solving this, you should do something like this:

> void show_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter,char *nullStr, int i){
>
> > for(i = 0 : *counter)
> >
> > > if (strcmp(nullStr, friends[i].First_Name) != 0)
> > >
> > > > // And here you should call the functions **getFirst** and **getLast**
> > > >
> > > > > }

And you should modyfy `getFirst` and `getLast` to print only the first/last name from the position `i` found in the function `showContact`

Comment: so when I print `printf("%s",friends[i].Last_name);` this is not printing from the position `i` found in the function?

Comment: In your actual code, when you call the function getFirst, it prints all the first names it finds and only after function returns, the function getLast is called and it prints all the last names it finds. So the behavior is this:

> call getFirst>> prints `john`, prints `jane` returns

> call getLast>> prints `smith`, prints `doe` returns

The data in the structure vector are ok, you dont print them the good way

Comment: is there a way that when I call the `getFirst` and `getLast` functions in the `Show_contracts` function, then I can use a `printf()` to print them out in a manner when it comes out the way that I need? ex. `printf("%s %s", setFirst,setLast)`. Obviously that doesn't work, but I was curious as to if there was a way to do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

The code below resolves all your problems:

> void show_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter,char *nullStr, int i)
>   {
>
> > for( i = 0; i < *counter; i++)
> >
> > > ```
> > >   if (strcmp(nullStr, friends[i].First_Name) != 0){
> > > ```
> > >
> > > > ```
> > > >     getFirst(friends, i);
> > > >     getLast(friends, i);
> > > >   }
> > > > ```
> > > >
> > > > }
>
> char getFirst(fr*friends , int pos)
>   {
>
> > ```
> >       printf("%s\n", friends[pos].First_Name);
> >
> >       return *friends[pos].First_Name;
> > ```
> >
> > > }
>
> char getLast(fr*friends , int pos)
>   {
>
> > ```
> >       printf("%s\n", friends[pos].Last_Name);
> >
> >       return *friends[pos].Last_Name;
> > ```
> >
> > }

Comment: I wish it did, but unfortunately all that did was make it worse. Implementing this code( and making the proper adjustments throughout the rest of the code) results in me getting the same first name printed out over and over. ex. `john smith` and `jane doe` would result in `john john`. :/

Comment: imposible, I tested the code before pasting it here. It works perfect!

Comment: did you copy and post it straight on to what I had provided earlier? I tried both copy and pasting yours and mine together and changing my program around to match what you provided.

Comment: I wouldn't normally ask, but could you just copy n paste what you ran in your compiler so I can see what the discrepancy is between our two codes? because I cant seem to find why yours runs perfectly and mine doesn't. Oh the joys of programming :).

Comment: I added you the whole code. It works for me. Put the code in an empty file and compile + run.

And btw, you can give me a thick if what I said helped you